# jupyter - how to comment out cells?

Tags: ipython, jupyter

Is it possible to comment out whole cells in jupyter?

I need it for this case:

I have a lot of cells, and I want to run all of them, except for a few of them. I like it that my code is organized in different cells, but I don't want to go to each cell and comment out its lines. I prefer to somehow choose the cells I want to comment out, then comment them out in one go (so I could later easily uncomment them)

Thanks

Answer (score 48):

Mark the content of the cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>/</kbd>. It will comment out all lines in that cell. Repeat the same steps to uncomment the lines of your cell.

Answer (score 28):

I think the easiest thing will be to change the cell type to 'Markdown' with <kbd>M</kbd> when you don't want to run it and change back to 'Code' with <kbd>Y</kbd> when you do.  In a short test I did, I did not lose my formatting when switching back and forth.

I don't think you can select multiple cells at once.

Comment: multiple cells can be selected at once

Comment: You need to use lowercase `m` (and lowercase `y`). Uppercase `M` will merge the selected cell with the subsequent one!

Answer (score 17):

If you switch the cell to 'raw NBConvert' the code retains its formatting, while all text remains in a single font (important if you have any commented sections), so it remains readable. 'Markdown' will interpret the commented sections as headers and change the size and colour accordingly, making the cell rather messy.

On a side note I use this to interrupt the process if I want to stop it - it seems much more effective than 'Kernel --> Interrupt'.

Comment: The problem is that the text still gets passed through during knitting, so this can break pdf or html conversion depending on the cell contents.

Answer (score 3):

You can switch the cell from 'Code to 'Raw NBConvert'

Answer (score 1):

I have two hacks to deal with the issue.

One is to convert all cells to the Raw format and not Code or Markdown. This essentially runs the code with incompatible Raw format code that I have and has very little runtime.

Another way is I keep all of my unused cells at the bottom and force an error with have a cell on top of those cells with the word "break" for a Code type cell.  This way when I run all, it runs everything I want to and errors right before running the cells I don't want to be run.